# Getting error when trying to implement CustomeUserControl

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Okay im trying to create a custom user control in asp.net web forms however am getting the following error message:

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

```
Parser Error Message: The file '/User%20Controlls/Header.ascx' does not exist.
Source Error:
Line 2:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="UsingUserContols.Default" %>
Line 3:  
Line 4:  <%@ Register src="User%20Controlls/Header.ascx" tagname="Header" tagprefix="uc1" %>
Line 5:  
Line 6:  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space from "User%20Controlls" folder text.

Rename it to "UserControlls"